# Are any two maps from a contractible space homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a contractible space and $Y$ be any topological space. For any two continuous maps $f, g : X \to Y$ from $X$ to $Y$, is it true that $f$ is homotopic to $g$?

I understand that it is true if $Y$ is path-connected.

Comment: This is false even for $Y$ path connected. Let $X= [0,1]$ and $Y = S^1$. Since $\pi_1(S^1)=Z$ there exist infinite functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ that are not homotopic.

Comment: @HelloDarkness The fundamental group is about equivalence classes of path homotopy (i.e a homotopy which also preserves the base point), not general homotopy. The statement OP asks about is true if $Y$ is path connected

Comment: Ok, so suppose that $Y$ is not path connected, then there exist $y,z \in Y$ with no path between them. Then take $f$ to be constant on $y$ and $g$ to be constant on $z$. A homotopy between these functions is a path.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the statement is true **if and only if** $Y$ is path connected. For the second direction, suppose any two continuous maps $f,g: X\to Y$ are homotopic. Take any two points $y_0, y_1\in Y$, and we will show there is a path in $Y$ which connects them. By assumption, the constant maps $f,g:X\to Y$ defined by $f(x)=y_0, g(x)=y_1$ are homotopic. Thus, there is a continuous function $F:X\times I\to Y$ such that:

$F(x,0)=y_0$ and $F(x,1)=y_1$ for all $x\in X$

Now choose any point $x_0\in X$ and define $\gamma:I\to Y$ by $\gamma(t)=F(x_0,t)$. This is a indeed a path between $y_0$ and $y_1$.